# docker and elevated priv

Tags: powershell, docker

Is it possible to run docker without elevated priv ex. (docker version).
Im trying to run a command on another machine (windows server with docker as service) with powershell invoke command but it seems as long as the docker insists on elevated priv i cannot.

So if i can get "docker verison" to work im all set.

The error i get is 
docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: Access is denied. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help

it works with an elevated powershell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal - by default, a local named pipe is used for the Docker CLI to communicate with the service (aka daemon).

For development use you can configure the host machine's Docker service ("daemon") for [TCP access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon) but this is the least secure option. Just put this text in file daemon.json:

```
{
    "hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}
```

Once this is done you can connect with e.g.

```
docker --host tcp://1.2.3.4:2375 version
```

If this is for production use, you probably need to look at a container orchestration system.

A middle ground would be to use`Attach-PSSession` to attach to an admin PowerShell session on the remote machine. This *still requires a privileged user* but does work remotely.

Comment: This allows **unrestricted root access** on your system to **anyone** who can reach it.  I’d never do this, even in a development setup.